# How to show a region on a image with CSS

Tags: css, image, region

I have a 125x250 image and I need to just display a 125x125 region of it.
Can I do this via CSS? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the CSS [`clip`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pos_clip.asp) property but it's a bit clunky to set up and, as @edd points out in his answer, works for absolutely and fixedly positioned images only.

I personally would create a 125x125 `div` and, depending on the situation, either

- Have the image be the div's `background-image` (you can even position it using `background-position`
- Put the image in it, and give the `div` `overflow: hidden` (advantage: It will still be an image element with an ALT text)

If you need the whole thing to behave like an image in the document flow, you can give the `div` the `display: inline-block` property (Not supported by older IEs).

Comment: *dispaly: inline; *zoom: 1; is the solution for display: inline-block in IE<8

Answer (score 2):

This technique is also called "sprites". An [ALA article from 2004](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites/) demonstrated the basics, another good and short introduction can be found at w3schools (www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp).

So it is basically a parent element being positioned `relative`. A child element has a defined size and a background like `background:url("sprite.png") 0 0;`. To use another portion of the sprite e.g. at another child element, you can define `background:url("sprite.png") -125 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS Clip property but it's a bit fiddly to set up because the image and parent need to be either absolute of fixed positioned. But it does work quite well once setup.

example:

```
img 
{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,125px,125px,0px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your image inside `div`

```
<div style="width: 125px; height: 125px; overflow: hidden;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```