# Cropping an image with PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, image, load, crop

I have an image called 'progressbar.png'. Is there a way that I could crop this image, with PHP or Javascript, each time the page loads the image will crop depending on the progress percentage and be loaded into the page. For example, if the image was 200px wide, at 25% progress the image would be cropped to only 50px wide.

Comment: There are [a lot of plugins that actually do this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) already

Comment: Don't crop, just use HTML div and change the width with javascript

Comment: `progress percentage` of *what*?

Comment: @Joseph the Dreamer  Do you have anything for PHP? Because that would be my preferred method. However, thank you for the link and I shall look into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a progress bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951903/how-to-make-a-progress-bar)

Comment: @Kevin Duke Correct me if I'm wrong, but that only resizes it. I wish for the right end to be cut off or the progress bar would look strange.

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour Is that relevant? I just need to be able to crop an image's width to a given percentage, whatever it may be.

Comment: Check out @SeanJohnson's answer below for what I mean

Comment: @DanielMarshall progress bar of what? live data? file upload? or static percentage image?

Comment: @DanielMarshall , my solution will crop your image. NOT resize it. Background images are not resized if they do not fit in the element, they're cut off.

Comment: Well, you sounded as if you meant page load progress, which would make a whole lot of difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a div, set the background of the div to your image, and manipulate the div's width to whatever you want.

HTML:

```
<div id="progressbar"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#progressbar{
background:url(progressbar.png) top left;
height:progressbarheightpx;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('progressbar').style.width='50px'
```

Or it could be done in PHP by simply printing out the width directly to the div:

```
<div id="progressbar" width="<?php echo $percent_done*200;?>px"></div>
```

Comment: Setting the background is a much better idea than wrapping an img tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the img tag in a div. Use css to mark the overflow as hidden and javascript to dynamically set the width. However you may want to look into jQueryUI's progress bar instead.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

Cropping serverside (with PHP) would require a request for a new file each time the percentage changes.

Cropping an image with JavaScript can be done by using `<canvas>` (see [Copy and crop images in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200374/1048572)), although this would be a huge overhead.

Just use CSS, it has a couple of techniques to show only a cutout of an element. See [CSS Display an Image Resized and Cropped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493296/1048572), [Clip images with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094023/clip-images-with-html-and-css) or [How to show a region on a image with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3708234/1048572)

BTW: There is usually no need to use an image for a progress bar. It is much easier with a simple DOM element appropriately styled, HTML5 even offers the `<progress>` tag. See [How to make a progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951903/how-to-make-a-progress-bar)